# No dividing lines for headers in `TableForm`

Tags: headers-footers, output-formatting

I seem to get this a lot, but I still can't find a systematic answer... The latest table I'm having trouble with is

```
table1 = Table[{x, "\[Rule]", x/2, 
"\[Rule]", (2*(x/2))/(1 + (x/2)^2), 
"\[Rule]", ((2*(x/2))/(1 + (x/2)^2))^k, "\[Rule]", 
     ((2*(x/2))/(1 + (x/2)^2))^k /. e -> 0 /. 
 k -> Infinity}, {x, {{1 + e}, {2 + e}, {3 + e}}}]; 
Labeled[TableForm[table1, 
 TableHeadings -> {{"x < 2", "x = 2", "x > 2"},
{"heading 1", "", 
 "heading 2", "", 
 "heading 3", "", 
 "heading 4", "",
 "heading 5"}}], 
Style["\nWHY NO DIVIDING LINES?\n", Bold], {Top}]
```

Why can't I get the thing to produce dividers between the `TableHeadings` and the body of the table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because `table1` isn't an array:

```
ArrayQ[table1]
(*False*)
```

You have a couple of options.  If you change your definition to make your input an array, for example by removing an extra level of lists from your definition of `x`:

```
table2=Table[
     {x,"->",x/2,"->",(2*(x/2))/(1+(x/2)^2),"->",((2*(x/2))/(1+(x/2)^2))^k,"->",((2*(x/2))/(1+(x/2)^2))^k/.e->0/.k->Infinity},
     {x,{1+e,2+e,3+e}}
]
TableForm[table2,TableHeadings->{{"x < 2","x = 2","x > 2"},{"heading 1","","heading 2","","heading 3","","heading 4","","heading 5"}}]
(* table with dividers *)
```

Alternatively add an explict `TableDepth` to force the input to be interpreted as a matrix.  This will show the nested lists that prevent the input from being an array:

```
TableForm[table1, TableHeadings -> {{"x < 2", "x = 2", "x > 2"}, {"heading 1", "", 
    "heading 2", "", "heading 3", "", "heading 4", "", "heading 5"}}, TableDepth -> 2]
(* Table with dividers and braces around list entries *)
```

If the input isn't an array of sufficient depth, `TableForm` falls back to legacy code that doesn't support dividers.  That may be overly strict, but it's how the code currently works.